# How to update the effects of dynamic templates for existing indices in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

If I define a template with a specific setting I can then update that setting in all existing indices by PUTTING to the `_settings` subpath of the index.

How would I do the same for [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html)? That is, if I define a dynamic template, how would I reflect this change in all existing indices as if the dynamic template had been defined when the index was created?

This is my dynamic template:

```
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "eks-*"
  ],
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "default_no_index": {
          "path_match": "^.*$",
          "path_unmatch": "^(@timestamp|auditID|level|stage|requestURI|sourceIPs|metadata|objectRef|user|verb)(\\..+)?$",
          "match_pattern": "regex",
          "mapping": {
            "index": false,
            "enabled": false
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch verion: 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dynamic template specifies (part of) the mapping of your index, and you cannot change the mapping of an existing index  ([Elasticsearch Documentation | Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#update-mapping)). This means that although you can update the (dynamic) mapping in your index template at any time, those changes will apply only to the new indices matching the template pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [@glenacota](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60137328/1037626) is not quite right, I believe. It confuses the documented inability to change an existing field mapping in an existing index with changing the "dynamic_templates" of that index. It is possible to read out the "dynamic_templates" from the existing index `_mapping`, take just that JSON element (array), add a new dynamic mapping to that array on JSON level, then POST that back the element to `_mapping`. Now, if you create a new field with a name covered by that new dynamic template, you'll find that the new field type (mapping) does in fact get filled from the dynamic template. And existing properties remain intact. I just checked that with Opensearch 1.3.4.